# Decoding HTML in an AngularJs expression

Tags: angularjs

What's the best way to decode HTML that is contained in strings passed to an Angular expression?

Example:

If I have a string returned from the server like this:

```
var some_val = "Hello <strong>World</strong>!"
```

How can I have it render the HTML rather than display it as text?

```
<!-- Renders to Hello <strong>World</strong>! -->
<span>{{ some_val }}</span>
```

*Update*: Here's actual use case in a repeater:

**Works (unsanitized)**

```
<div ng-repeat="category in some_list">
   <p>{{ category.name }}</p>
   <p ng-repeat="bullet in category.bullets">{{ bullet.desc }}</p>
</div>
```

**Doesn't work at all**

```
<div ng-repeat="category in some_list">
   <p ng-bind-html="category.name"></p>
   <p ng-repeat="bullet in category.bullets" ng-bind-html="bullet.desc"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include the angular-sanitize.js file which contains the ng-bind-html directive?

Comment: That was definitely part of the problem, but I had to use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As described [here, in the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive%3angBindHtml):

```
<span ng-bind-html="some_val"></span>
```

Remember that some_val must be a angular model (basically, a `$scope.some_val` must exist somewhere in your app)

**EDIT:**

I should clarify: ng-bind-html is a service in the module `ngSanitize`, **which isn't included in the angularJS core**. `ng-bind-html-unsafe` is part of the core `ng` module, but it includes the string you supply it without sanitizing it (see the example in [the ngBindHtmlUnsafe docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe)).

If you want/need to use ngBindHtml, you need to include ngSanitize - [available here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/)

Comment: You can get away from using a variable by using quotes: `<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="'Hello <strong>World</strong>!'"></span>`

Comment: Hmm I'm using it in a repeater and it isn't working.  Maybe it's a bug.  I'll update the original question with the repeater code in case I missed something obvious.

Comment: According to a comment on the docs' page: Question: "Looks like the result is not innerHTMLed but just rendered as the value of ng-bind-html attribute." Answer: "There is a ng-bind-html-unsafe directive that acutally puts the content as innerHTML. 
This is not documented atm." I hope it helps.

Comment: I had already referenced it in my answer, but indeed, it needed clarification :)

Comment: My problem was indeed twofold, was missing the angular-sanitize lib and needed to use `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.

Comment: What is the solution for the Angular 2+?

Comment: @AsadShakeel https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example